# "Extra argument 'error' in call" error in Swift 2

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am new to programming and learning through a *Beginning Xcode* book. It is not on Swift 2 (but I am learning through it anyways for now).

In one of the projects it is teaching how to create a twitter-type app.  Here is the code:

```
    func retrieveTweets() {
        tweets?.removeAllObjects()

        if let account = selectedAccount {
            let requestURL = NSURL(string: "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json")
            let request = SLRequest(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeTwitter,
                requestMethod:  SLRequestMethod.GET,
                URL: requestURL,
                parameters: nil)

            request.account = account
            request.performRequestWithHandler()
            {
                responseData, urlResponse, error in

                if (urlResponse.statusCode == 200)
                {
                    var jsonParseError : NSError?
                    **self.tweets = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(responseData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &jsonParseError) as? NSMutableArray**
                }

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
```

*I get the "extra argument 'error' in call" error at the code with the ** around it (self.tweets...). I've tried putting the "do"/"catch" block code but honestly have no where to put it, or know what I am doing with it :)

Can someone help me on this?  Need to know what to change in the bolded code (or around it) to make it work.

Thanks!!

Comment: Remove the error argument, add the try for that line instead. `do{ self.tweets = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(responseData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSMutableArray} catch _ {//error}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using Swift 2. `JSONObjectWithData` is now a throwable function. You have to wrap it in a `do { try ... } catch` block:

```
if (urlResponse.statusCode == 200)
{
    do {
        self.tweets = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(responseData, options: [.MutableContainers]) as? NSMutableArray
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescritpion)
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked great! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Your instinct to use the do/catch block was correct. Because `JSONObjectWithData` can throw an error, you need to call it with `try`. The error parameter is unnecessary when dealing with Swift functions that can throw. Try something like this.

```
if (urlResponse.statusCode == 200) {
    do {
        self.tweets = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(responseData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)
    } catch {

        print("\(error)")
    }
}
```